# Windows Script to automatically disable and then enable COM port

Tags: script

I have a pc at work which its com port always hangs on boot up. It is windows 7.
In order to get it to work you need to disable and enable the com port manually. This is not an option for the setup of the computer.

Does any one have a script or have the code which will allow me to disable and enable a com port?

I want to run the script on start up to automatically disable and enable the port.

Comment: you cant disable the port in BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft's comdisable.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819036)

> For example, to enable COM port 2:

Use:

`comdisable /enable com2`

There is a disable as well and listing of ports.

You can disable before the computer shutsdown.

EDIT: You can try and call the script at startup but it might not work if Windows holds before.